# How to count unique entries in a column across multiple columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data set that looks something like this
[data set example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhIkn.png)

I am trying to find unique entries in each of the columns

I managed to do it for 1 column utilizing count

> `ORDDF4ALDEX_Count <- DataframeAldex %>%    count(Zotu63864)`

however, I was wondering if there was a way to do so for all columns without entering each column name via count

Thanks

Comment: Paste the data instead of an image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are wanting to count how many unique numbers there are in each column, then we can use `n_distinct` inside `summarise` from `tidyverse`.

```
library(tidyverse)

iris %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), ~ n_distinct(.)))
```

Or with base R:

```
sapply(iris, function(x) length(unique(x)))
```

**Output**

```
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1           35          23           43          22       3
```

Comment: I just needed the first part, basically, I wanted to see unique values in my columns including NA values, the next step is to figure out the value of the unique values in each column, thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
DataframeAldex2 <- apply(DataframeAldex, 1, function(x) paste0(x))
dim(unique(DataframeAldex2))
```

Answer (score 0):

We may use `fndistinct` from `collapse`

```
library(collapse)
fndistinct(iris)
Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width      Species 
          35           23           43           22            3
```